# How to work with an ElasticSearch cluster and NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I really like the NEST API, and of course ElasticSearch. A large part of the appeal is the ability to scale out a cluster very easily. I have have 3 nodes consisting of 1 master and 2 read slaves. Does the NEST client provide any support for load balancing and failover across the cluster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, by choice.

Loadbalancing is based on many heuristics that differ per application. A lot of setups already have hardware/software loadbalancers in front of the elasticsearch cluster.

On top of that elasticsearch already load balances so even if the client hits one node all the time, the cluster can let other nodes coordinate the search.

Of course failover is something that needs to be handled in the application (if the hardware/loadbalancers don't already take care of this), I might release a simple implementation as a separate nuget package that can keep a pool of clients but for now my main focus is polishing NEST's API to be 1.0 stable/fully documented.

**UPDATE 2014**

Since NEST 1.0 cluster failover and connection pooling is built into the client:

```
var node = new Uri("http://mynode.example.com:8082/apiKey");
var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(new[] { node1, node2, node3 });
var config = new ConnectionConfiguration(connectionPool);
var client = new ElasticsearchClient(config);
```

http://nest.azurewebsites.net/elasticsearch-net/cluster-failover.html

http://nest.azurewebsites.net/elasticsearch-net/connecting.html

http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/connecting.html

Comment: @Martin Laarman, did you have time to work on the mentioned client pool package, and if not, what is the preferred way of connecting to an ElasticSearch cluster - simply choosing one random node?